# What chord is this?

Tags: guitar, chords

0-0-8-7-9-7

http://www.updike.org/harmony/frets.cgi?0,0,8,7,9,7

I'm not sure if that is correct.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-HKKXxUMH4) is the song I'm trying to play. I'm just trying to figure out what the first chord is, but if you recognize what the other chords are I would like to know what those are as well.

Comment: The answer to your questions depends on the context in which the chord is used.  Give us more details, like what key the song is in, what chords are used before and after etc.  A link to a recording of the piece would help as well.

Comment: I don't see any tab or other text indicating the desired chord.

Comment: I edited the question to have a chord diagram, rather than the text description the question had. It works fine on Chrome; will put back in a chord description.

Comment: Are the two top string open or not used? In the latter case, fret 8 on D = Bb, fret 7 on G = D, fret 9 on B = Ab, fret 7 on E = Cb, which looks like a Bb9b chord to me. This chord is a somewhat less common dominant in Eb major (3b) and minor (6b) keys. However, the first chord played in the video is a Dm7, which makes me wonder whether the chord diagram is really for the first chord.

Answer (score 4):

From the look of the video I think what you are looking for is an Dm7...

It seems the chord progression is something like Dm7 G7 Em7 A7...

I don't know how to put the chord diagram in... Maybe somebody else can help with that

The chord diagram in the question is way off... It starts from the fifth fret with an Dm7

[here is a link to the chord](http://www.hobby-hour.com/guitar/chords.php?chord=dm7-fret5)

Answer (score 1):

The chord is a D minor 7 (Dm7).  This chord can be played a number of ways, but in the video he is barring the 5th fret and playing the Am7 form.  In this form, you would not typically play the 6th string.

The 5th and 6th strings are NOT open.  Your index finger is used as a "barre" - it frets all of the strings at the 5th fret.  Then you use the other fingers to play a transposed Am7 chord.  Normally this is played as follows:

6th string - not played
5th string - barred at 5th fret with index
4th string - 7th fret with ring finger
3rd string - barred at 5th fret with index
2nd string - 6th fret with middle finger
1st string - barred at 5th fret with index

Comment: Is this way of playing the chord considered to be hard? What's the easiest way to play it?

Comment: Are you sure that's right? It doesn't sound right.